# Setting precision while reading the values from Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I need to read the values from excel sheet using c# - OleDB connection.
Excel sheet has both numeric values and percentage values.

The excel cell has the value as 0.25%.

But the actual value of the cell is 0.247337730504847%

While reading the values using OleDB connection, my DataSet gives me 0.25% instead of 0.247337730504847%

Please help.

Below is the connection string used to read the excel file.

```
connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                                  Data Source=" + filelocation + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO""";
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually my excel sheet also has some cells with 'Accounting' formating. I need to read those values. So I have used IMEX=1.

I need to full precision on numeric values as well as need to read accounting formatted cells.

please help

Comment: Using IMEX=1 forces the provider to interpret the data as text, regardless of the actual type of the data.  Sounds like you don't like that.

Comment: It must be something to do with the cell formatting then

Comment: Actually my excel sheet also has some cells with 'Accounting' formating. I need to read those values. So I have used IMEX=1. Is there any other way to read accounting values without IMEX=1?

Comment: @Hans Passant - Sorry. you were right. I am not getting full precision in both numeric value and percentage value using IMEX = 1. Is there any other way? I need full precision as well as need to read account formatting cells